# Creating a lists of lists with new element in each position

Tags: list, haskell, insert

i'm new in the haskell world and i'd like to know how to insert a value in each position of a list in haskell, and return a lists of sublists containing the value in each position. For example:

```
insert' :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
insert' a [] = [[a]]
insert' a list = ??
```

To get something like:

```
insert' 7 [1,2,3] = [[7,1,2,3],[1,7,2,3],[1,2,7,3],[1,2,3,7]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
insert' :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
insert' y [] = [[y]]
insert' y xss@(x:xs) = (y : xss) : map (x :) (insert' y xs)
```

While the empty list case comes natural, let's take a look at `insert' y xss@(x:xs)`. We essentially have two cases we need to cover:

1. `y` appears in front of `x`. Then we can just use `y : xss`.
2. `y` appears somewhere after `x`. We therefore just insert it in the rest of our list and make sure that `x` is the first element with `map (x:)`.

Comment: @Zeta `before` and `behind` is not about order, but about **positions** in the list, there is no pre assumption of `a` an instance of `Ord`.

Comment: @Zeta I have modified to **appears**, hope makes it clear. I am not an native English speaker, I would appreciate it if there are any suggestions expressing this.

Comment: In the part (f y xs), what this do is to call the function using the list without the first element right?

Comment: @john yes. recursive is about find the sub-problem, the pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It's incredible to see how simple the answer was, I think that I need alot of practice to get this language

Answer (score 0):

Although [@delta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45976870/67579) is definitely more elegant, here a solution with *difference lists*. If we insert an element `x` on every location of list `ys = [y1,y2,...,yn]`, the first time we will insert it as head, so that means we can construct `x : ys`.

. For the second element of the resulting list, we want to construct a list `[y1,x,y2,...,yn]`. We can do this like `y1 : x : y2s`. The next lists will all have a structure `y1 : ...`.

The question is: how can we write a recursive structure that keeps track of the fact that we want to put elements in the head. We can use a function for that: we start with a function `id`. If we now call `id (x:ys)` then we will of course generate the list `(x:ys)`.

We can however, based on the `id` function, construct a new function `id2 = \z -> id (y1:z)`. This function will thus put `y1` in the head of the list and then add the list with which we call `id2` as tail. Next we can construct `id3 = \z -> id2 (y2:z)`. This will put `y1` and `y2` as first elements followed by the tail `z`.

So we can put this into the following recursive format:

```
insert' :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
insert' x = go id
    where go d [] = [d [x]]
          go d ys@(yh:yt) = (d (x : ys)) : go (d . (yh :)) yt
```

So we redirect `insert'` to `go` where the initial difference list is simply the `id` function. Each time we check if we have reached the end of the given list. If that is the case, we return the basecase: we call `[x]` (as tail) on the difference list, and thus construct a list where we append `x` as last element.

In case we have not yet reached the last element, we will first emit `d (x : ys)`: we prepend `x` to the list and provide this as argument to the difference list `d`. `d` will prepend `y1 : y2 : ... : yk` up to the point where we insert `x`. Furthermore we call recursively `go (d . (yh :)) yt` on the tail of the list: we thus construct a new difference list, wehere we insert `(yh :)` as tail of the list. We thus produce a new function with one argument: the tail after the `yh` element.

This function produces the expected results:

```
*Main> insert' 4 []
[[4]]
*Main> insert' 4 [1,2,5]
[[4,1,2,5],[1,4,2,5],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,5,4]]
*Main> insert' 7 [1,2,3]
[[7,1,2,3],[1,7,2,3],[1,2,7,3],[1,2,3,7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do as follows;

```
import Data.List

spread :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
spread x xs = zipWith (++) (inits xs) ((x:) <$> tails xs)

*Main> spread 7 [1,2,3]
[[7,1,2,3],[1,7,2,3],[1,2,7,3],[1,2,3,7]]
*Main> spread 7 []
[[7]]
```

So this is about three stages.

1. `(x:) <$> tails xs` is all about applying the `(x:)` function to all elements of `tails xs` function. So `tails [1,2,3]` would return `[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]` and we are to apply an `fmap` which is designated by `<$>` in the inline form. This is going to be the third argument of the `zipWith` function.
2. `(inits xs)` which would return `[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`, is going to be the second argument to `zipWith`.
3. `zipWith (++)` is obviously will zip two list of lists by concatenating the list elements.

So we may also express the same functionality with applicative function functors as follows;

```
spread :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
spread x = zipWith (++) <$> inits <*> fmap (x:) . tails
```

In this case we `fmap` the `zipWith (++)` function with type `[[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]` over `inits` and then apply it over to `fmap (x:) . tails`.

It could get more pointfree but becomes more complicated to read through (at least for me). In my opinion this is as best as it gets.